# How to change last position in toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try build some project with JQuery toggleClass. I want make position toggle follow some last record data. 
This my **HTML**

```
<div class="action-lock">
  <div class="toggle-pane">
    <div class='unique' id='switch'>
      <div class='toggle-text-off'>Unlocked</div>
      <div class='glow-comp'></div>
      <div class='toggle-button'></div>
      <div class='toggle-text-on'>Locked</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this **JQuery**

```
$scope.last = "a";
$('.unique').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   if($scope.last == "b"){
       $(this).toggleClass('toggle-on');
   }else{
       $(this).toggleClass('toggle-off');
   }
});
```

I try but toggle position always in `Locked`, I don't know how to make position toggle from data `$scope.last`. Please help me to solved this problem. Thanks

Comment: @kindly update working code.

Comment: @Dhaarani what you mean ?

Comment: where you have to toggleclass $('.unique') or toggle-text-on

Comment: In unique but position toggle in toggle-text-on or toggle-text-off

Comment: check my answer if any doubt let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('controllerName', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.last = ""
$scope.toggleclick = function(last){
   debugger;
   if(last == "a"){       
       $(".toggle-text-on").toggleClass('toggle-on');
       $(".toggle-text-off").toggleClass('toggle-off');
   }else if(last != "a"){
       $(".toggle-text-on").toggleClass('toggle-off');
       $(".toggle-text-off").toggleClass('toggle-on');
   }
};
}]);
```

```css
.toggle-text-off.toggle-on,.toggle-text-on.toggle-on{display:block;}
.toggle-text-off,.toggle-text-on{display:none;}
.maginbt10{margin-bottom:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controllerName">
<div class="action-lock">
<input type="text" ng-model="last" name="mail"  class="maginbt10" />
  <div class="toggle-pane">
    <div class='unique' id='switch'>
      <div class='toggle-text-off' ng-class="{'toggle-on':last != 'a'}">Unlocked</div>
      <div class='glow-comp'></div>
      <div class='toggle-button'></div>
      <div class='toggle-text-on' ng-class="{'toggle-on':last == 'a'}">Locked</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: @Rizka Nugroho check this answer

Answer (score 0):

You question isn't clear but this is my guess from your explanation.

```
$('.unique').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $(this).toggleClass('toggle-on').toggleClass('toggle-off');

});
```

and html

```
<div class="action-lock">
  <div class="toggle-pane">
    <div class='unique toggle-on' id='switch'>
      <div class='toggle-text-off'>Unlocked</div>
      <div class='glow-comp'></div>
      <div class='toggle-button'></div>
      <div class='toggle-text-on'>Locked</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My question i want make position in toggle folow some data like if a-> tooggle-on and if not a->toggle-off

Comment: @RizkaNugroho what is the default state?

Comment: like in my code the default state, simply I want make position toggle follow $scope.last

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('controllerName', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.last = "a";
$scope.toggleclick = function(){
   if($scope.last == "a"){
       $(".toggle-text-on").toggleClass('toggle-off');
       $(".toggle-text-off").toggleClass('toggle-on');
       $scope.last = "b";
   }else{
       $(".toggle-text-on").toggleClass('toggle-on');
       $(".toggle-text-off").toggleClass('toggle-off');
       $scope.last = "a";
   }
};
}]);
```

```css
.toggle-on,.toggle-text-off.toggle-on{display:block;}
.toggle-off,.toggle-text-off{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controllerName">
<div class="action-lock">
  <div class="toggle-pane">
    <div class='unique' id='switch'ng-click="toggleclick()">
      <div class='toggle-text-off' ng-click="toggleclick()">Unlocked</div>
      <div class='glow-comp'></div>
      <div class='toggle-button'></div>
      <div class='toggle-text-on' ng-click="toggleclick()">Locked</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: if i change $scope.last="b" result always Locked. I want if $scope.last="a"->Locked or $scope.last="b"or whatever->Unlocked

Comment: it still locked when i open snippet, I want if i run snippet position toggle if $scope.last="a"->Locked or $scope.last="b"or whatever->Unlocked without click. maybe my question unclear